# Can I get online payment in USD or Euro in my Indian bank account registered with indian company?

Tags: currency, payment, online

I am going to register my company in India and will open an indian bank account with company name. The payment mode will be online, so please let me know whether I can get the payment in USD and Euro or not?
Also suggest the best payment gateway for online payment in USD or EURO.

Answer (score 1):

1. You bank Account always has a "native" currency. If it´s in INR all payments to that account in a any other currency are automatically exchanged to rupees by your bank. Usually fees apply and the conversion rate may not be the most favorable.
2. It is possible to open accounts in other currencies. So you may choose to hold these currencies and exchange in a point in time and through an exchange that may give you better conditions. Speak to your bank about this. If they can´t offer these services to you, seek another bank. May also be worthwhile to talk to an international / foreign bank that has a branch office in India.
3. The best payment gateway will largely depend on the customers, the sums involved, the frequency of the payments and the variety of currencies you accept. You should also look into foreign tax implications. The are specialized payment-providers who do all of that for your, for a fee.